# Prevent "exceeded maximum execution time" faliure email on google apps script because of browser messages not closed

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, alert

### Backgroud:

I have multiple spreadsheets that, on certain scenarios, pop a browser simple message box to the user.

### Problem:

It is not rare that users forget to click "OK" which result in me getting a faliure email for "exceeded maximum execution time".

### Questions:

- Is there a way to not get the email in case it only have this kind of
  faliure?
- Is there a way to auto-close the message box after a defined time
  (say 10 seconds)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Turning off notification emails isn't possible, but you can instead set up a Gmail filter to force these emails to skip the inbox.*

*It is also not possible to programmatically simulate the UI alert being clicked, nor is it possible to auto-close the box after 10 seconds. You could instead use a toast message to inform the user, instead of a message box, as a workaround*.

#### Dealing with the Failure Emails:

- In the failure notification email, the first paragraph will show something like this:

> Your script, Sciript Name, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65104377/).

Following the 'click here' link takes your to triggers, but as you can see, you can only change the freuquency of these emails, not turn them off:

[image]

To remove these automatically from the inbox, head to https://mail.google.com and enter the following in the search bar:

```
from:apps-scripts-notifications@google.com "Script name"
```

replacing `Script name` with the name of the script which you are receiving notifications about. Make sure to keep them inside the quotation marks.

Next, click the down arrow (▼) on the right-hand side of the search bar, and click `Create filter`.

Here, select your behaviour: I recommend either selecting `Skip the Inbox (Archive it)` if you want to keep the email without it cluttering your inbox, or simply `Delete it` if you don't wish to see them at all.

You can also check the box next to `Also apply filter to matching conversations.` if you have many in your inbox already.

Click `Create filter` and you're done - you will no longer receive these emails.

#### Toasts

As I previously mentioned, it isn't possible to time-out or auto-close a message box.

If, however, you only wish to inform the user of some information, and having them click okay isn't necessary, you can instead [display a toast message in Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg,-title,-timeoutseconds):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.toast('Thanks for doing the thing!', 'Title', 10);
```

This will appear like so:

[image]

#### References:

- [Class Spreadsheet - `toast(msg, title, timeoutSeconds)` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast(String,String,Number))